# Change order of horizontal axis in SSRS scatter chart?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

My `SSRS` scatterchart looks like the following. The horizontal axis shows the hours, in this case Hr 0-14.

So I'm trying to change the order of the horizontal axis, so it goes from recent to older (ie. 14-0).

I went to `Category Groups`, then to `Sorting`, and changed the Order of `dimhour` from `A to Z` to `Z to A`. Nothing changed.

The `tsql` script also returns the data ordered by DimHour Desc. Nothing changed with that either.

What else  can I do? Here's the test query used for the scatterchart:

```
select  1 as 'dimhour',  9 as 'dept', 99.567 as 'Percent'
union
select  4 as 'dimhour', 13 as 'dept', 99.741 as 'Percent'
union
select 11 as 'dimhour', 16 as 'dept', 99.374 as 'Percent'
union
select 11 as 'dimhour',  7 as 'dept', 99.706 as 'Percent'
union
select 11 as 'dimhour',  4 as 'dept', 99.575 as 'Percent'
union
select 14 as 'dimhour',  1 as 'dept', 99.741 as 'Percent'
order by dimhour desc
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Edit:

I tried a solution that Hannover Fist suggested (set **Horizontal Axis** set to **Scalar**), and it sorta works, but it doesn't display the hours in intervals. As you can see, it doesn't display in 1-unit intervals, even though it's set that way in the **Horizontal Axis** properties (`Interval = 1`).

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me when I create a new table.

My guess is that you have the **Horizontal Axis** set to **Scalar**. This seems to sort it based on the value regardless of the Sort on the Category.

Changing the **Axis Type** to **Category** should make it work correctly.

[image]

Comment: I tried changing axis type to Category, and it sorta works, but it doesn't show the hours in 1-unit intervals, even though it's set that way in the Horizontal Axis properties (Interval = 1). I edited my initial post to show the chart with this change. Thanks.

Comment: Ah - it's because there's no data for those intervals. :( You would need to have a value for each hour in order for it to display each hour. Does your actual data have all hours?

Comment: You're right. I was looking at the actual query that does have all hours. This sample one doesn't. Let me try it out with the real query and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under Scale options you can click on the Reverse direction option:

> Reverse direction Select this option to reverse the direction of the
>   chart. For example, by default, a column chart displays the y-axis on
>   the left side of the chart and categories from left to right. When
>   this option is selected, the chart displays the y-axis on the right
>   side of the chart and categories from right to left.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934393(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I had already checked that option before posting, but as you said, it also moves the Y-axis to the right, and that makes the chart look odd. But worse-case scenario, I can use that.